# PHP Amazon MWS Feed - ProductImage - XML error on line -1

Tags: php, xml, amazon-mws

I'm working on a custom module to send some products to amazon via PHP Amazon MWS.
I read all the guides and the module is up and running now (sending all the feeds: Product, ProductImage, Inventory, Price) but I have a **problem sending the image**.

The strangest thing (and this is where I got stuck and I'm thinking of throwing myself out of this 3rd floor office) is that testing my XML ProductImage FEED on Amazon Scratchpad it works!!
(https://mws.amazonservices.it/scratchpad/index.html)

But if I take exactly same XML feed it fails with a strange error from Amazon WS (syntax error invalid char at line -1, you know).

I'm sure my module works well because it simply take a product from a queue, generate the XML feed needed, and send it with the same function amazon wrote in its documentation example. (infact I sent 5000 products with success, except for the images)

I read another answer pretty near, but the solution was to remove the "xml version="1.0" part, but I really don't think that's the problem. (Because the ScratchPad tool send it correctly with a positive submission feed result).

This is a XML Image Feed as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>A1VWJ2240S9NYA</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>ProductImage</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
   <MessageID>1</MessageID>
   <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
   <ProductImage>
       <SKU>0582</SKU>
       <ImageType>Main</ImageType>
       <ImageLocation>http://www.mywebsite.com/images/product/myimage.jpg</ImageLocation>
   </ProductImage>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Can somebody help me with this?
Any suggest or comment is valued.

Thank you

Comment: Just a blind shot - check (e.g. using some hex viewer) if there are no UTF-8 [BOM characters](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the very beginning of the XML file. UTF-8 BOM is 3 characters: `EF BB BF`.

Comment: Yeah great shot Dawid, I thought it too but here every xml generated is php generated (simpleXML) and sent via CURL. It'all UTF8 without BOM. I should have the same problem on the other feed too.
Thank you very much anyway!